# Pandas convert mixed type column values to numeric where possible

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
disp_name               measured_value    measure_time 
temperature             99.3              05/06/2020 13:32:40
pressure                2                 05/06/2020 13:32:40
colour                  orange            05/06/2020 13:32:40
name                    measure_name      05/06/2020 13:32:40
```

Currently all the variables in the 'measure_value' column are strings. I want to keep the format of the dataframe as it is but convert all the strings to their correct types, i.e. 99.3 should be a float and 2 should an int. 'orange' and 'measure_name' can remain as str.

The dataframe is quite large and the next step is to loop through with groupby('measure_time'), so I don't want to make separate columns in the table for each variable.

I have tried using pandas to_numeric and astype, but these don't seem to be able to handle mixed type columns.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without writing some complex loop structure which involves copying the whole DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

use `object` type and convert cells values individually:

```
# setup:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','two','3', '4', 'five']})

# convert only values that start with number (enter your own criteria if needed)

df.loc[df.a.str.slice(0,1).isin(list('0123456789')), 'a'] = \
    df.loc[df.a.str.slice(0,1).isin(list('0123456789')), 'a'].astype(int)

# test
for i in range (df.shape[0]):
    print (df.a[i], type(df.a[i]))

1 <class 'int'>
two <class 'str'>
3 <class 'int'>
4 <class 'int'>
five <class 'str'>

    print(df.info())
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       5 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 168.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Ok thanks I can see this will work, I would like to avoid this sort of solution however as it doesn't take advantage of the vectorised operations in pandas and my dataframe is v large

Comment: I edited the answer to give vectorized example. pls accept and upvote.